# Why won't selenium see my element?

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing my first ever selenium test.  It's amazing and I've got it logging into my application which makes me feel giddy.  Here's my automated UI stuff using ChromeDriver:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
Authentication.LogInAsAdmin(driver);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
TenantManagement.CreateTenant(driver, false);
```

Authentication.LogInAsAdmin works just fine.  My single page angular app (upon login) loads additional content and displays it.  TenantManagement.CreateTenant(driver, false) is where things go wrong.  The first line in that piece is failing:

```
public static bool CreateTenant(IWebDriver driver, bool testLogin)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("TenantsTab")).Click();
    ...
}
```

As you can see, I have a thread sleep before this call just to make sure everything is loaded before trying to find the element.  When looking at the html in Chrome dev tools (element inspector), I see:

```
<li ng-class="{active: active, disabled: disabled}" id="TenantsTab" ng-repeat="Tab in SelectedArea.Pages | filter:lessThanTwo" ng-click="trackTab(Tab)" active="Tab.active" heading="Tenants" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <a ng-click="select()" tab-heading-transclude="" class="ng-binding">Tenants</a>
</li>
```

This element is definately present when the thread wakes back up and tries to find it, but it's not being found.  Any clues on what I'm doing wrong here or how one would go about troubleshooting this when using selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this seems to be using [selenium wait functionality](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)  (which I just discovered).  By adding this:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

to the beginning of my CreateTenant() method, selenium waits up to 10 seconds for an element to become available, and adding that worked.  Not sure why the thread sleep doesn't.

Comment: It's always better to avoid .sleep in selenium and to let implicit wait do it for you.

Comment: With the `Thread.sleep` as you have it in your code, it will wait for 1 second before trying to find the element. This does not guarantee the availability and/or visibility of the element. If you bump the sleep time to 10 seconds it will probably work. But now you are forcing your code to wait for 10 seconds even if the element becomes available within, let's say 5 seconds. That is the main reason not to use thread sleep as it binds you to a hard limit.